# How to get xscreensaver/gnome screensavers working on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, 23.10, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I am getting this error when trying to use xscreensaver

```
xscreensaver-systemd: 10:30:07: connection failed: "org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver" in use by pid 2462 (/usr/libexec/gsd-screensaver-proxy)
xscreensaver: 10:30:07: pid 17484: xscreensaver-systemd exited unexpectedly with status 1
```

When using gnome-screensavers no error is shown but it immediately just takes me to screenshield and blanks the screen.
Command I used was `gnome-screensaver-command -a`